# Facebook Comments Plugin - Comments Not Showing in Wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have Facebook Comments appearing correctly on one page on my site, but can't get them to appear on this new page:

http://www.radionowhere.net/fb-comment-tester/

I first tried to get them to work by just taking FB's code and pasting it into the page manually, then tried again by installing Alex Moss' Facebook Comments plugin. In both instances, the FB comments did not appear (right now, the shortcode that's supposed to generate the plugin's FB comments is appearing as text.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: Got it. If anyone with a similar issue comes across this, make sure your shortcode syntax is exactly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. If anyone with a similar issue comes across this, make sure your shortcode syntax is exactly correct.